# Can I remove old installs of dot net framework when installing a new version?

Tags: .net-framework, .net-4.0

I'm running out of disk space and could not install version 4 of the dot net framework so I'm thinking of removing old installs (2 and 3 with service packs) to make room for the newer version. Will things stop working or is the dot net framework backwards compatible?

Comment: Also take a look at [Piriform CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). It's a freeware very very very efficient to junk useless files (iis log files, recycled items, application's caches, etc.)

Comment: If you use Web platform installer, you can also empty `C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers` to spare some space

Comment: Short answer (prior to keyboardP's fix for it below) is **Yes** things will stop working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remove the previous frameworks, then you'll have to edit the application config files of applications that target pre-4.0 frameworks to get them to work.

```
<supportedruntime version="v4.0.x"></supportedruntime>
```

There's an explanation [here](http://neilblackburn.blogspot.com/2009/10/net-framework-40-backward-compatibility.html) and [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/08/03/installing-net-framework-v4-0-and-running-net-2-0-3-0-3-5-3-5sp1-applications.aspx). If you run quite a few .NET programs, I'm sure there are other things on your machine that you can uninstall that has lower priority.

Comment: updating all app.config file of all application, already installed or installed in the future will be so painful, you'll regret not to have bought a $80 new hard drive.

Comment: Agreed. I fail to see the only resort to obtaining more disk space being to uninstall previous .NET frameworks.

Comment: I concur - repairing and compacting a PST or clearing the temp folder (+older temporary internet files) would be a much easier way to clear some space!

Comment: Working for a huge company that using XP on 30 GB c drive I have to make the best of what I got - that's engineering :)

Comment: You have my sympathy :D Ultimately, it is possible to do that but you'll have to manually fix any program you come across that was built against the previous frameworks. Might be easier to remove 1.1/2.0 if you think most programs at 3.0+ and see if that provides enough space.